# Как сделать, чтобы ELSE срабатывал после выполнения всего цикла FOR?

Tags: java, if, for

В данном случае ELSE срабатывает сразу после первой итерации, что неприемлемо.

```java
class Roman {
    public String numRo(String s) throws Rss_Exception {
        String[] arabsk = {"0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"};
        for (int j = 0; j < arabsk.length; j++) {
        }
        String[] rimsk = {"I", "II", "III", "IV", "V", "VI", "VII", "VIII", "IX", "X"};
        for (int n = 0; n < rimsk.length; n++) {
            if (s.equals(rimsk[n])) {
                s = arabsk[n + 1];
            } else {
                throw new Rss_Exception("ERROR");
            }
        }
        return s;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Вам здесь циклы не нужны в принципе.

```
public class Roman {

    private final static String[] ROMAN_NUMBER = {"I", "II", "III", "IV", "V", "VI", "VII", "VIII", "IX", "X"};

    public static String convert(String number) {

        try {
            return ROMAN_NUMBER[Integer.valueOf(number.trim()) - 1];
        } catch (NullPointerException | NumberFormatException | ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Number " + number + " not found");
        }

    }

}
```

Или в двух направлениях с использованием BiMap (https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.guava/guava/31.0.1-jre):

```
import com.google.common.collect.BiMap;
import com.google.common.collect.ImmutableBiMap;

public class Roman {

    private final static BiMap<String, String> ROMAN_NUMBER = new ImmutableBiMap.Builder<String, String>()
                    .put("1", "I")
                    .put("2", "II")
                    .put("3", "III")
                    .put("4", "IV")
                    .put("5", "V")
                    .put("6", "VI")
                    .put("7", "VII")
                    .put("8", "VIII")
                    .put("9", "IX")
                    .put("10", "X")
                    .build();

    public static String toRoman(String number) {
        return ROMAN_NUMBER.get(number);
    }
    
    public static String fromRoman(String number) {
        return ROMAN_NUMBER.inverse().get(number);
    }
    

}
```

Comment: Цикл не нужен при конвертации в римские цифры, а исходный вопрос о противоположном направлении :)

Comment: @Alex Rudenko возьмите BiMap от гугла и конвертируйте куда хотите в одну строку)) код дополнил

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int n = 0; n < rimsk.length; n++) {
  if (s.equals(rimsk[n])) {
    return arabsk[n + 1];
  }
}
throw new Rss_Exception("ERROR");
```

Comment: Спасибо, но не работает(( В случае ввода иного значения (вне массива) метод тупо ничего не возвращает.. Уже пробовал вместо ошибки String значения подставлять, все равно ничего не возвращает, если ввожу иное значение..

Comment: @Евгений Вы неаккуратно скопировали к себе мой код. Не используйте слово "тупо". Вы не за школой курите с местной шпаной, а общаетесь с прoфессионалами. Метод не может "ничего не возвращать".

Comment: ответ с хоть каким-нибудь пояснением лучше ответа без какого-либо пояснения.

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin "Это точно." - тов. Сухов